# XSL Replacing an empty node with data

Tags: xml, xslt

This should be simple, but I am unable to figure this one out. I have XML files that contain some empty nodes that I want to replace with a fixed string via XSL. If the node contains data it is fine, but if it is empty I want to replace it with a string "18010101"

For Example:

Before:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TopNode>
  <SubNode1>
    <SubNode2>
      <SubNode3>
        <SubNode4>
          <date_of_birth></date_of_birth>
        </SubNode4>
      </SubNode3>
    </SubNode2>
  </SubNode1>
</TopNode>
```

After:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TopNode>
  <SubNode1>
    <SubNode2>
      <SubNode3>
        <SubNode4>
          <date_of_birth>18010101</date_of_birth>
        </SubNode4>
      </SubNode3>
    </SubNode2>
  </SubNode1>
</TopNode>
```

I have a similar issue where I replace a fixed value with another fixed value with xsl.

```
  <xsl:template match="transaction_type[text()='15']">
    <xsl:text>5</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
```

It works fine, but when I try to do a similar fix for the date issue it doesn't seem to work.

```
  <xsl:template match="date_of_birth">
    <xsl:if test="date_of_birth = ''">
      <xsl:text>18010101</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `xsl:if` to:

```
<xsl:if test=". = ''">
```

Or change your `xsl:template match` to:

```
<xsl:template match="date_of_birth[. = '']">
```

Comment: I tried that before. The '<xsl:template match="date_of_birth[text() = '']">' doesn't perform a match when I debug the output. '<xsl:template match="date_of_birth">' does match

Comment: It looks like this is working. <xsl:template match="date_of_birth"> <xsl:if test=". = ''"> <date_of_birth>18010101</date_of_birth> </xsl:if> <xsl:if test=". != ''"> <date_of_birth> <xsl:value-of select="text()"/> </date_of_birth> </xsl:if> </xsl:template>

Comment: Another example of why it's nearly always wrong to use text(): an empty element doesn't have any text nodes, so there can't be a text node equal to ''! Use `match="date_of_birth[.='']"`

Comment: +∞ to @MichaelKay for "it's nearly always wrong to use text()" :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do this,

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TopNode>
  <SubNode1>
    <SubNode2>
      <SubNode3>
        <SubNode4>
          <date_of_birth></date_of_birth>
        </SubNode4>
      </SubNode3>
    </SubNode2>
  </SubNode1>
</TopNode>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="date_of_birth">
      <xsl:if test=". = ''">
         <date_of_birth>18010101</date_of_birth>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test=". != ''">
         <date_of_birth>
            <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
         </date_of_birth>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TopNode>
   <SubNode1>
      <SubNode2>
         <SubNode3>
            <SubNode4>
               <date_of_birth>18010101</date_of_birth>
            </SubNode4>
         </SubNode3>
      </SubNode2>
   </SubNode1>
</TopNode>
```